# Search and print specific columns from tab delimited file?

Tags: bash, awk

I can use awk to print the nth column from a file; the cut command also can do a similar thing.. but I require the column to be taken based on its name, for example:

```
col1 col2 col3 col4
2 5 3 1
6 4 7 1 
3 6 5 9
7 9 7 8
```

and if I give a list of column names as input: e.g. col1, col3 (is is going to be a long list of column names, so it would help if the input could be an array)

the output would be

```
col1 col3
2 3
6 7 
3 5
7 7
```

does anyone know how I might do this in bash?

Comment: [`man cut`](http://man.he.net/?section=all&topic=cut)

Comment: Read the first line (headings) into array: `array=( $(head -n+1 filename) )`. Then you can loop though the array picking the field number(s) to print from matching names.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$ awk -v s="col1 col3" 'BEGIN{split(s,v," ");for (i=1;i<=length(v);i++)a[v[i]]=1} NR==1{split($0,b,"\t")} {for (i=1;i<=NF;i++)if (b[i] in a)printf "%s\t",$i;print""}' file
col1    col3
2       3
6       7
3       5
7       7
```

#### How it works

- `-v s="col1 col3"`

  Define an awk variable `s` containing a space-separated list of the columns that you want to keep.
- `BEGIN{split(s,v," ");for (i=1;i<=length(v);i++)a[v[i]]=1}`

  Create an associative array `a` whose keys are the column names and whose values are one for columns in the string `s`.
- `NR==1{split($0,b,"\t")}`

  Save the columns names in an associative array `b`.
- `for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) if (b[i] in a) printf "%s\t",$i; print""`

  For each column, `i`, if the column name, `b[i]` is in array `a`, print the column followed by a tab.

  To finish, `print ""` prints a newline.

Answer (score 1):

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN { FS=OFS="\t" }
NR==1 {
    for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) {
        if ( match(cols,"(^| )"$i"( |$)") ) {
            colNrs[++numCols] = i
        }
    }
}
{
    for (i=1;i<=numCols;i++) {
        printf "%s%s", $(colNrs[i]), (i<numCols?OFS:ORS)
    }
}

$ awk -v cols="col1 col3" -f tst.awk file
col1    col3
2       3
6       7
3       5
7       7
```